# flask_table send entire row data on buttonCol form

Tags: javascript, python, flask, request

[image: example table]
This table is created with flask_table where it displays data from a database.
Every row of the table will look similar to this example with a sign in button.

Currently when I click the sign in button it appends the database id of that item to form action endpoint that goes back to python flask.

This is how the table is setup in flask_table:

```
class myTable(Table):
id = Col('id', show = False)
sign_in_button = ButtonCol('Sign In', 'endpoint_to_send_form_to', url_kwargs=dict(id='id'))
```

So given this...currently, when I click sign in button (assuming this item's id number in the database is 1). It makes its form action=**"/endpoint_to_send_form_to/1"**

This is how its being received in flask:

```
@app.route('/endpoint_to_send_form_to/<int:id>', methods=['POST'])
def endpoint_to_send_form_to(id):
    #doing python/flask stuff
```

And then I can do python/flask things with that item in the database since I know its id, however, **what I would like is:**

**Upon button click, receive post info of the Classroom, Activity, and Fund selected option (only in the row of the button clicked) as well.
I was wondering if there was a flask_table way to do that, but honestly, I'm currently thinking about seeing if javascript can add that data to the form.**

I'm thinking I should be able to get that form data with something like:

```
data = request.form.get("nameOfForm")
data.classroom
data.activity
data.fund
```

Answer (score 1):

So I guess it took me asking this question to dig deep and reading some documentation to come up with a solution.

The docs:

https://flask-table.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

First off I'd like to correct something I thought previously, but was wrong:

```
data = request.form.get("nameOfForm")
data.classroom
data.activity
data.fund
```

I was thinking I had to give the name of the form, but I can just get the name of the elements within the form directly:

```
element = request.form.get("nameOfElementInForm")  #as shown at the bottom of this page
```

I was still able to use flask_table to get this to work, however I needed to use javascript as well.

### In flask_table:

```
class myTable(Table):
id = Col('id', show = False)
sign_in_button = ButtonCol('Sign In', 'endpoint_to_send_form_to', url_kwargs=dict(id='id'), form_hidden_fields={'class_number':'test_class','activity':'test_activity','fund':'test_fund'}, button_attrs={'onclick':'update_form_info(this)'})
```

The docs say:

> "You can pass a dict of hidden fields to add into the form element
>   with the form_hidden_fields kwargs. The keys will be used as the name
>   attributes and the values as the value attributes."

I just filled them with values for testing, and to have something to print when I found them in the DOM, I will be overwriting them anyway.

The docs also say:

> You can pass a dict of attributes to add to the button element with
>   the button_attrs kwarg.

I used this to add a onclick function and passed in "this" so I'd have the button clicked on to make sure I'm searching, and editing the right row of data.

### In Javascript

```
function update_form_info(ele) {
        var $row = ele.closest('tr')
        var classroom = jQuery('td:nth-child(6) select', $row).val()
        var activity = jQuery('td:nth-child(7) select', $row).val()
        var fund = jQuery('td:nth-child(8) select', $row).val()

        var $hidden_eles = ele.closest('td')
        jQuery('input:nth-child(1)', $hidden_eles).val(activity)
        jQuery('input:nth-child(2)', $hidden_eles).val(classroom)
        jQuery('input:nth-child(3)', $hidden_eles).val(fund)
```

Since the tables structure is the same, I know exactly which column number contains what I'm looking for, I learned about .closest('some element type') which starts at the element and then goes up the DOM for the nearest element type. Anyway, I find the element selected in the table option select field and update my hidden elements thats inside the form, so now we can do our flask/python stuffs.

### In Python:

```
activity = request.form.get("activity")
class_number = request.form.get("class_number")
fund = request.form.get("fund")
```

Now we got our values in python!